# GLSL Compute Shader Setting buffer with lookup table results in no data written, setting the same buffer with other data works

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compute-shader

I am attempting to implement a slightly modified version of [this standard marching cubes algorithm](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) in a compute shader.
I have reached the stage at which `triTable` is used to insert the correct vertex indices into a buffer and have modified the table to be 1 dimensional (`const int triTable[4096]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,8,3...}`)

The following code shows the error that I am experiencing (this does not implement the algorithm however it demonstrates the current issue fully):

```
layout(binding=1) buffer Grid
{
    float GridData[]; //contains 512*512*512 data volume previously generated, unused in this test case
};
uniform uint marchableCount;
uniform uint pointCount;

layout(std430, binding = 4) buffer X    {uvec4 marchableList[];}; //format is x,y,z,cubeIndex

layout(std430, binding = 5) buffer v {vec4 vertices[];};
layout(std430,binding = 6) buffer n {vec4 normals[];};
layout(binding = 7) uniform atomic_uint triCount;
void main()
{
    uvec3 gid = marchableList[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].xyz; //xyz of grid cell

    int E = int(edgeTable[marchableList[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].w]);
    if (E != 0)
    {
        uint cubeIndex = marchableList[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x].w;

        uint index = atomicCounterIncrement(triCount);
        int tCount = 0;//unused in this test, used for iteration in actual algorithm
        int tGet = tCount+16*int(cubeIndex); //correction from converting 2d array to 1d array

        vertices[index] = vec4(tGet);
    }
}
```

This code produces expected values: the vertices buffer is filled with data and the atomic counter increments

changing this line:

```
vertices[index] = vec4(tGet);
```

to

```
vertices[index] = vec4(triTable[tGet]);
```

or

```
vertices[index] = vec4(triTable[tGet]+1);
```

(demonstrating that triTable is not coincidentally returning zeros)
results in what appears to be a complete failure of the shader: the buffer is filled with zeros and the atomic counter does not increment. No error messages are output when the shader is compiled. `tGet` is less than 4096.

The following test cases also produce the correct output:

```
vertices[index] = vec4(triTable[3]); //-1

vertices[index] = vec4(triTable[4095]); //also -1
```

showing that triTable is in fact implemented correctly
What causes the shader to have issues in these very specific cases?

Comment: "*No error messages are output when the shader is compiled.*" Does that mean that you're checking for shader compile/link errors, or that you're expecting `glGetError` to return that an error has happened? Because `glGetError` does not report shader compilation failure; only the compile/link status queries do that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am detecting compiler errors using `glGetShaderInfoLog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more surprised that `const int triTable[4096] = {...};` compiles at all. That array, if it is actually needed, is 16KB in size. That's a lot for a shader, even if the array lives in shared memory.

What is most likely happening is that, whenever the compiler detects usage of this array that it can't optimize it out to a simple value (`triTable[3]` will always be `1`, so the compiler doesn't need to store the whole table), the compilation either fails or results in a non-functional shader.

It would be best to make this table a uniform buffer. An SSBO might work too, but some hardware implements uniform blocks through specialized memory rather than with a global memory fetch.

Comment: This solves the problem in the test case, although I haven't tested it with the actual code yet. Is there a way to query the size limit of hard-coded arrays? 16KB didn't seem like an unmanagable amount, especially considering it worked in my CPU implementation of the same code. Does this limitation apply to source code size or size of memory taken up by the actual compiled array?

Comment: @jcg: "*especially considering it worked in my CPU implementation of the same code.*" You're talking about a *far* more limited execution environment.